# ¿Cuál es la representación de "int2" en MongoDB?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Necesito hacer la representación de estos datos de postgresql:

```
  "tienda" int2 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  "devolucion" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
```

para mi schema hecho en Mongoose.

```
const DevSchema = new Schema({
tienda:{
    type:Number,
    default: 0,
    required:true
},
devolucion:{
    type:Number,
    default: 0,
    required:true
}
},{'collection':'schema','timestamps':true});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const DevSchema = new Schema({
tienda:{
    type:Number,
    default: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 99,
    required:true
},
devolucion:{
    type:Number,
    default: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 9999,
    required:true
}
},{'collection':'schema','timestamps':true});
```

Aún no existe una representación exacta de la memoria reservada para int, de hecho MongoDB no tiene dicha característica, sin embargo podemos limitarla con Mongoose y sus keywords `min y max`